# Reading custom format file using apache beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am new to Apache Beam. I have a requirement to read a text file with the format as given below

```
a=1
b=3
c=2

a=2
b=6
c=5
```

Here all rows till an empty line are part of one record and need to be processed together (eg. insert to the table as columns). The above example corresponds to a file with just 2 records.
I am using **ReadFromText** to read the file and process it. It reads each line as an element. I am then trying to loop and process till I get empty lines.

ReadFromText returns a **PCollection** and I have read that PCollection is an abstraction of the potentially distributed dataset. My doubt is while reading, will I get records in the same order as in the file. Or will I just get a collection of rows where the order is not preserved.  What solution can I use to solve this problem?

I am using python language. I have to read the file from the GCP bucket and use Google Dataflow for execution.

Answer (score 0):

No, your records are not guaranteed to be in the same order. PCollections are inherently unordered, and elements in a PCollection are expected to be parallelization, that is distinct and not reliant on other elements in the PCollection.

In your example you're using TextIO which treats each line of a text file as a separate element, but what you need is to gather each set of data for a record as one element. There are many potential ways around this.

1. If you can modify the text file, you could put all your data on a single line per record, and then parse that line in a transform you write. This is the usual approach taken, for example with CSV files.
2. If you can't modify the files, a simple solution for adding your own logic for reading files is to retrieve the files with [FileIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.30.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html) and then write a custom [ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo) with your own logic for reading the files. This is not as simple as using an existing IO out of the box, but is still easier than creating a fully featured Source.
3. If the files are more complex and you need a more robust solution, you can implement your own Source that reads the file and outputs records in your required format. This would most likely involve using [Splittable DoFns](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#splittable-dofns) and would require a fair amount of knowledge in how a [FileBasedSource](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.30.0/apache_beam.io.filebasedsource.html) works.

Comment: thanks a lot. withDelimiter seems to be a good fit for my problem. Any idea, how I can adapt this is in python code. I got an error when trying to use with the ReadFromText.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I thought you were using the Java SDK for some reason. Unfortunately, the Python SDK does not support changing the delimeter in TextIO. I'll update my answer with recommended alternatives.